# Mongodb connection pools with cross region replicas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-atlas

We have a cluster hosted on Mongo Atlas (M50, AWS) with cross region replicas in 5 other regions. This allows my application servers in those regions to read from a local replica using `readPreference=nearest` which is much faster.

The M50 instance size has a maximum of 16000 connections.

The issue I face is that the connection pool creates a connection to each node in the cluster.  With 5 other regions, each having 10 application servers and each server having an application pool of 100 (as is default), that's 5000 connections to every single node when they will only ever read from the replica in the local region.  These connections take away from the connections available to application server in the the primary region which is doing all the writes (5000k writes per second).  The primary region has 20 application servers.  These serves are set to have a minimum of 500 connections each which creates a minimum of 10000 connections. That's a total of 15000 connections.

This creates a problem as we sometimes run out of connections when traffic spikes as those pools increase in size to cope with the additional load.  The minimum pool size is required to ensure the application remains responsive when the traffic spikes (if we don't do this we see a lot of `MongoWaitQueueFullException`s and unacceptably high response times).  We could set the maximum pool size but this limits throughput and we see timeouts.

Is there any way that the application pools in the replica regions can be prevented from creating connections to every single node in the cluster?

We don't want to increase the instance size as it doubles the cost of the cluster.

The application is written in .NET 6 (minimal API) with MongoDB driver version 2.16.

Comment: how do you create MongoClient?

Comment: Created once and stored as singleton in Program.cs - var client = MongoClient(connectionString); builder.Services.Configuration.AddSingleton(client);

Comment: by `connections`, you mean connections from a server side?

Comment: Yes, from my application server to the cluster nodes

Comment: `MongoWaitQueueFullExceptions` can happen by different reasons, you should provide the full exception details. But, also this is driver/client side exception, where connection you mentioned are about server side. Let's start with the whole exception message